# Setting up a WebServer on the Raspberry PI - Suggestions on approach

Tags: raspbian, web-server, pi-2, lighttpd

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

I am doing imaging diagnostics outdoors using a RPI 2 and a DSLR camera (to which the Pi connects and controls via gphoto2). I have a bunch of python scripts on the pi which automate the process of collecting images and process them.

Nonetheless, I would like to setup a webserver on the pi, which will also host a webpage to which I can connect from lets say an ipad and run the imaging scripts from this webpage. I will not have internet connectivity on field so I would like the pi to work as a sort of "router", so that from the ipad's wifi connections I can connect to the pi, logon to the webpage hosted on the pi and run the scripts which will return to the ipad's browser a preview image of the result of the scripts.

I know this is confusing how I explained it, but I hope it makes somewhat sense. I just need pointers on how this should be done (names of webservers I should use, etc.), not the entire process. I'll figure that out afterwards.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome -- but this is not really [a pi-specific question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) since the hardware is irrelevant, and you are using a general purpose operating system.  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) if you have not yet, and note this is a Q&A format, *not* open ended discussion -- you seem to have several divergent questions, a vague one about webservers (use any one you like, and please no "Which one do you think is best?" opinion based questions), presumably you want to use python if any programming is required,

Comment: ...since that is what you are comfortable with (but web programming questions involving python belong on our larger sibling site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)); and another question about using the pi as a local WLAN router (which you may find some Q&A's about here, but it is really a general linux question and belongs on on our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)).   Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with

sudo apt-get install lighttpd

which will install the lighttpd web server.

The next thing I'd do is assign the Pi a static IP address.

As for the rest, I have no idea.